# Prove that $p^2$, with $p$ prime, is a pseudoprime to the base $b$ if and only if $b^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I have to prove that $p^2$, with $p$ prime, is a pseudoprime to the base $b$ iff  $b^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$.

I don´t have any idea, so ¿could someone helps me please?

Comment: 1) Use \pmode, p for 'parentheses. 2) What have you tried? What  have you learned so far regarding this particular topic?

Comment: I`m in an advance course of cryptography.

Comment: I didn't mean that, what have you learned before you were given the problem and what your difficulties are. Be more specific to prevent closing and avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried the following:

By definition, $p^2$ is a pseudoprime to base $b$ iff $b^{p^{2}-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$. On the other hand, by Euler's theorem $b^{p^{2}-p} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$ for all $b$ with $(b,p^2)=1$. So $p^2$ is a pseudoprime to base $b$ iff $ 1 \equiv b^{p^{2}-1} \equiv b^{p^{2}-1}(b^{p^2-p})^{-1} \equiv b^{p-1} \pmod{p^2}. $

Comment: Why ask then? The solution is correct.

Comment: Because I don`t noted to use Euler's theorem when I posted my question. So now I write my answer to check it´s correct.